# Could a Jedi know who shot first?

Tags: jedi, star-wars

This answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68676/33509) got me thinking.

If a jedi knows a shot is fired just before it was fired, could he/she know who shot first?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Asking questions purely as a joke is discouraged (even if the question is funny). The site guidelines say: "You should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems** that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: You may believe this is a joke but I was serious in my question. I'm not new to SE I was seriously asking this question since I'm in debate at work over it.

Comment: Your account was only created today, so in that sense you are "new". :-) If this is really a serious question, can you be more specific? What specific shooting incident is the Jedi meant to evaluate? If it's the famous Han vs Greedo scene, there is no need for Jedi skills -- Han clearly shoots first in the original, Greedo in the (widely despised) special edition.

Comment: This account for SE.scifi as you can see on my profile I have 24 other accounts. Ill try to expand on my question but I believe you answered it.

Comment: Even if your 24 other accounts weren't almost all single-rep accounts that are equally new, you are new to SciFi.  Regardless, "Who shot first" is a reference to Han and Greedo's cantina scene, and could mean any number of things if *not* referring to that particular scene.  Hence our desire for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you’re referring to the infamous cantina scene between Greedo and Han Solo, where in the original release, Han Solo clearly shot his blaster before Greedo could, but in the Special Edition release, Greedo fires a shot before Han Solo.

In that particular situation, there are only two potential Jedi that were in the Cantina - Obi-Wan and Luke (ignoring expanded universe content, behind-the-scenes Jedi, and secret Wookiee Jedi theories).

Luke obviously could not have been able to tell who shot first due to his lack of training, but what about Obi-Wan?  It is possible, if he had been focused on the exchange, that he could tell which of the two had shot first.

But since he had just finished his negotiations with Han Solo over passage to Alderran, he was not focused on the exchange between the smuggler and bounty hunter.  There is no indication that Jedi have the ability to percieve past events, so we have no reason to believe Obi-Wan knows who shot first.  In fact, unless a Jedi had been monitoring that exchange at that specific time, **no one in the Cantina could know which of the two characters shot first**.

If, however, Han believes he shot first, then Obi-Wan may have been able to tell later by reading Han’s feelings, but since no one should ever talk about that scene ever again for any reason, the galaxy may never know.